# Enable autoplay HTML5 video in chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, browser, html5-video

In my project, I need to autoplay HTML5 video in browser when page is loaded.

I have tried a several javascript solutions but none of them works.

I read that android browser is blocking autoplay due to protect from downloading a lot of data.

**Can be this blocking feature turned off in browser/chrome/operation system settings ?**

I cannot find any working solution how to enable autoplay. I have searched over plenty of stackoverflow posts and many other sites ...

By the way, I am using `android 4.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:  We are looking at it, but the reason it is turned off by default is that we are really concerned about the battery and bandwidth on a users mobile device that we would rather require the user to perform a gesture.

Comment: This seems to work fine now in Chrome 59 on Android 7.1.1. I wouldn't say the situation around battery life has drastically improved over the last 3 years (still those single-day charges...), but I suppose the price of mobile bandwidth has dropped significantly that the Chrome team is less concerned about having video's auto-play.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome this seems to be working now, anno 2017: HTML5 videos play automatically in Chrome (59) on Android (7.1.1).

Note that the videos start muted. You can enable autoplay with sound on Android Chrome by navigating to `chrome://flags` and set `gesture requirement for media playback` to `disabled` (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117225/185053) answer).

(Note that unfortunately disabling this flag seems to have no impact on an embedded YouTube video. I have openened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45264838/185053) for this.)

Answer (score 0):

add "muted" attribute in video tag like;

```
<video autoplay muted>
 ...
</video>
```

it will work. Google chrome doesn't autoplay the videos with sound. So, you will need to mute it.