# YouTube embed: How to enable *non-muted* autoplay in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

This question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117225/185053) which has a solution for HLTML5 videos, except that changing the `chrome://flags` to set `gesture requirement for media playback` to `disabled` has no influence on a YouTube embedded player.

I have built a webapp I use to learn music, and loop specific parts of Youtube music videos to learn how to play the song. [Here](https://vallenato.fr/aprender/lleno-de-ti.html?p=32) is an example. This works fine on a computer, but using Chrome (59) on Android (7.1.1) I have to tap the video each time it starts again to put the sound back on. Not handy when trying to use my hands to learn playing the music ;)

The code I'm using to embed the player and interact via Javascript can be found [here](https://github.com/e2jk/vallenato.fr/blob/c5346acfcdb033dc7b087c7b552c18265d7bb4f8/vallenato.fr.js#L129).